# Can't figure out why this regex doesn't work (multiple lines of text with "starts with" qualifier)

Tags: java, regex

It's so hard to find out why this isn't working, my research indicates it should work.  I'm try to do this logical match - start of line has from: then any amount of characters then start of line has sent: .  Please see code, I would think it would print match found but doesn't:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test2 {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Pattern lineDividerGuessMatchPattern = Pattern.compile("(?m)(?i)(^from:)(.*?)(^sent:)");

        String testString = "cheese \n"
                + "from: cheese\n"
                + "sent: bacon";

        Matcher m = lineDividerGuessMatchPattern.matcher(testString);

        if(m.find())
            System.out.println("Match found");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the `(?s)` flag too ([DOTALL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL) mode) to make `.` match line terminators. This finds a match:

```
Pattern lineDividerGuessMatchPattern = 
    Pattern.compile("(?msi)(^from:)(.*?)(^sent:)");
```

Comment: Another thing to do would be to add a newline character `\n` in the regex to match "Hey, there's the end of a line here"

Comment: @Revan: That would work too. The `^` already ensures that a new line is encountered though.

Comment: This whole thing ended up being an xy problem, I had orginally tried using (?s) but another thing was screwing it up at that time.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm try to do this logical match - start of line has `from:` then any amount of characters then start of line has `sent:`

You should use `(from:[^\n]*\nsent:)`

Here is [demo](http://regex101.com/r/rS3aG4/20)

Pattern explanation:

```
  (                    group and capture to \1:
    from:                'from:'
    [^\n]*               any character except: '\n' (newline) (0 or more times)
    \n                   '\n' (newline)
    sent:                'sent:'
  )                    end of \1
```

Comment: As per rule you are just looking for `from:` anything then in next line `start:`. Keep the regex simple as possible.

Comment: You missed the part where from has to be start of line I think, but I do believe your answer better solves the problem as a whole if you can address

Comment: I took DOTALL off and used this, which I think solves my problem better since there is a requirement that there be only one newline between from and sent - (?mi)(^from:)(.*?)\n(^sent:)

Comment: Which is not per my requirements in the question.  I will give you points for making me think about the problem a little more and driving to a better solution.  Thanks!